# Errors with Maven and Eclipse integration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

i'm totally new to the use of Eclipse with Maven, i am trying to follow a tutorial for using a java library, but fail on prerequisite : http://code.google.com/p/dkpro-core-asl/wiki/DeveloperSetup

immediately after the end of the last click "finish" of the page, if i look to my Eclipse windows, i think that something went wrong, as i have many errors and some small in Eclipse Package Explorer (i also do not get the differents points between a red exclamation mark, a small white cross on red (think this is one is an error mark) or what must be the "warning symbol" (yellow exlamation mark triangle).

so i have many different kind of errors, and no idea on how to solve them, i copy the full log below.

my errors are of the form :

```
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency:jar:0.4.0:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin *:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.toolbox-asl  line 1  Maven Problem
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\stephane\.m2\repository\de\tudarmstadt\ukp\dkpro\teaching\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency\0.4.0\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency-0.4.0.jar' de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl     Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl     Unknown Java Problem
```

please, if you have any clue on how to solve them,

i am wondering if i do not forget some king of elementary checkout or so, as i looks like almost everything is broken ?

thank u

(the expected tutorial is : "First Programming Steps with DKPro Core")

logs as image : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/dkprocoreaslmaven201204.png/

---8<---

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to read artifact descriptor for edu.berkeley.nlp.lm:edu.berkeley.nlp.lm.berkeleylm:jar:1.0b2 pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:4.0.1:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.io-asl:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph-asl:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata-asl:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.resources-asl:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile   pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation-asl:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.core:jar:0.4.0:compile pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.corpus:jar:0.4.0:compile   pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency:jar:0.4.0:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.ngram:jar:0.4.0:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.1:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1:compile   pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.uima:jVinci:jar:2.3.1:compile   pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.uima:uimaj-adapter-vinci:jar:2.3.1:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.uima:uimaj-core:jar:2.3.1:compile   pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.uima:uimaj-cpe:jar:2.3.1:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.uima:uimaj-document-annotation:jar:2.3.1:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.apache.uima:uimaj-tools:jar:2.3.1:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact org.uimafit:uimafit:jar:1.2.0:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact pcj:pcj:jar:1.2:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile  pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile   pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Missing artifact xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile    pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.coref-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.corpus-asl   line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.parameter-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.arktweet-asl line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.frequency-asl    line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.aclanthology-asl  line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.bnc-asl   line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.jdbc-asl  line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.tei-asl   line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.web1t-asl line 1  Maven Problem
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:build-tools:jar:3 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced pom.xml /de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.toolbox-asl  line 1  Maven Problem
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\stephane\.m2\repository\de\tudarmstadt\ukp\dkpro\teaching\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency\0.4.0\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency-0.4.0.jar' de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl     Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl     Unknown Java Problem
```

---8<---

EDIT :

i think i have installed the eclipse setup (but with Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857) as required by the tutorial that is :

```
Subclipse 1.6.x
    update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x 
m2eclipse 0.10.0 or higher.
    update site: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e 
Maven SCM handler for Subclipse
    update site: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras
```

here is the output of mvn clean package command from the directory where there is a pom.xml files :

```
[... here i am skipping as there are more 700 lines ... these below are last one :]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.054s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 18 11:18:31 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 93M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.aclanthology-asl: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\eclipseWorkspace\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core-asl\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.aclanthology\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.aclanthology-asl
```

EDIT 2 :

another very strange things => maybe the "mvn dependecy:resolve" or the "mvn clean package" has done something for me as after a computer reboot, almost all errors have disappeared and now only have 2 in Eclipse "Problems" tab ! 
(but still 225 items warning)

The 2 remaining errors are : and i have a red exclamation mark (what is it standing for ?) on the de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl in package explorer

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\stephane\.m2\repository\de\tudarmstadt\ukp\dkpro\teaching\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency\0.4.0\de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency-0.4.0.jar' de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl     Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl     Unknown Java Problem
```

still did not know what is it asking me !

LAST EDIT :

so reading answers provided by Kal (thank u a lot for helping), i am really wondering if my trouble do not also come from missing jars or some "build path" referenced libraries (i am really new to Maven/Eclipse). As from the Build errors for de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl (the one with red exclamation marks from EDIT2) that i have i get the following exception trace :

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl: Could not resolve dependencies for project de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.uimafit:uimafit:jar:1.2.0 (compile), xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 (compile), xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1 (compile), de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency:jar:0.4.0 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.2 (compile)]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:190)
```

[...]

is it not that i should have installed xerces, xalan, uimafit, junit or something like that to told where to find them ? I thought everything was inside the tutorial, or handled directly by Maven, but may be am i wrong ???

i had tried to do :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\junit-4.8.2.jar -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\uimafit-1.2.0.jar -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\xalan-2.7.1.jar -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar \
```

after manually downloading each files from mvnrepository.com website and putting them in d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\ 
of course, i can not find de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.teaching.frequency:jar:0.4.0 there.

```
mvn clean install:install -file -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\junit-4.8.2.jar -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\uimafit-1.2.0.jar -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\xalan-2.7.1.jar -Dfile=d:\downloaded\dependencies-for-DKPro-Core-ASL\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar \ -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

was no more successful and ended with :

```
[INFO] Deleting D:\eclipseWorkspace\maven.1334761781732\branches\1.2.x\de.tudarm
stadt.ukp.dkpro.core.io.text\target
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DKPro Core ASL - IO - XMI 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT

[...]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DKPro Core ASL 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) @ de.tudarmstad
t.ukp.dkpro.core-asl ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping DKPro Core ASL
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL .................................... FAILURE [0.139s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Anomaly API ...................... SUCCESS [0.048s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - FeaturePath API (ASL) ............ SUCCESS [0.074s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Metadata API ..................... SUCCESS [0.227s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO API ........................... SUCCESS [0.085s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Part-of-Speech API ............... SUCCESS [0.060s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Common API ....................... SUCCESS [0.075s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Lexical Units API ................ SUCCESS [0.117s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Structured and Semi-Structured Data API  SUCCESS [0.044s
]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Syntactic Units API .............. SUCCESS [0.274s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - CAS Transformation API ........... SUCCESS [0.042s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Named Entity Recognition API ..... SUCCESS [0.083s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Frequency Providers API (ASL) .... SUCCESS [0.015s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - MMAX2 (ASL) ................. SUCCESS [0.070s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - Text ........................ SUCCESS [0.090s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - XMI ......................... SUCCESS [0.083s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - XML ......................... SUCCESS [0.059s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - WSDL (CPL) .................. SUCCESS [0.096s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - Wikipedia (LGPL) ............ SUCCESS [0.114s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - PDFBox 0.7.3 (BSD) .......... SUCCESS [0.088s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - NEGRA ....................... SUCCESS [0.127s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - TreeTagger (free for research) ... SUCCESS [0.113s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - IMS Corpus Workbench ........ SUCCESS [0.044s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - IO - ANNIS2 ...................... SUCCESS [0.063s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Tokenization Toolkit ............. SUCCESS [0.134s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - CAS Transformation (ASL) ......... SUCCESS [0.216s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Jazzy (LGPL) ..................... SUCCESS [0.159s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - JWordSplitter (ASL) .............. SUCCESS [0.036s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - LanguageTool (LGPL) .............. SUCCESS [0.062s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Norvig's Spelling Correction ..... SUCCESS [0.046s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Snowball (BSD) ................... SUCCESS [0.243s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - TextCat (LGPL) ................... SUCCESS [0.062s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - BananaSplit (ASL) ................ SUCCESS [0.046s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Stop Word Remover (ASL) .......... SUCCESS [0.505s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - N-Gram Tools ..................... SUCCESS [0.307s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Part-of-Speech Filter ............ SUCCESS [0.058s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Dictionary Annotator ............. SUCCESS [0.344s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Examples ......................... SUCCESS [0.184s]
[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Distribution ..................... SUCCESS [0.007s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.815s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 19 11:13:27 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3
.1:install-file (default-cli) on project de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core-asl: The
artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR] [0]  'groupId' is missing.
[ERROR] [1]  'artifactId' is missing.
[ERROR] [2]  'packaging' is missing.
[ERROR] [3]  'version' is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

have also see that there was some complining about : "The dependencies resolving doesn't work correctly. The new m2eclipse plugin doesn't resolve the dependencies until the end." that may be involved ?

and i'm still badly stuck :/ and still too new to the maven/java/eclipse platform tricks...

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml? Are you using m2e?

Comment: Pom.xml file is here : http://www.sendspace.com/file/r0yt4d

and yes i think i have m2e installed, do not know if eclipse/maven/ is using it or no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you seem to have some dependency jars which seem to be proprietary (I may be wrong) secondly even the public libraries like Apache libraries cannot be downloaded. Are you behind a firewall? Looks like Maven cannot reach the Maven Central to download all the dependency jars as well as plugins. Make sure that you are using the correct version of maven compatible with your project.

If you are checking out a huge project, I advice you to first do a top level build (`mvn clean package`) in console. This will ensure that all the plugins and dependencies are downloaded and then you can tackle problems of importing this project into eclipse. Alternatively you can do `mvn dependency:resolve` to download all the dependencies.

Comment: Looking at the link you have provided for setting up the project, I can see that it needs you to configure some repositories in your Maven settings.xml file. Have you done that already? Also, output of your "mvn clean package" suggest that there are test failures, which can also fail the build.

Comment: yes i have already added the repositories in the <mypathtomaven-3.0.4>/conf.setting.xml file. Also when doing mvn dependecy:resolve i end up with a 

    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 7.116s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 18 13:59:37 CEST 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/40M

while ending as already told with a failure when doing "mvn clean package".

Comment: i have edited my question another time. You will see that most errors has disappeared, even if i do not know why.

Comment: Looks like the latest output you have posted is of Eclipse? You are still missing a dependency jar, looking at the name it looks like the jar is a sub module of the your project itself. Delete the project from eclipse. Do "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" on command line and then import project into eclipse as maven project. Your "mvn package" fails due to test failures.

Comment: yes, i must be missing something somewhere, when doing the mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true i still get a failure on the "[INFO] DKPro Core ASL - Frequency Providers API (ASL) .... FAILURE [0.737s]" which may be correlated (guessing that from the name) to the : "Build errors for de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.frequency-asl". Has edited another time to but the Exception Trace

Comment: Consult the project mailing list for more help, this looks project specific.

Comment: ok, i have posted on the project mailing list, thank you for your kindly help. Best.

Comment: Thanks you for this answer.

`mvn dependency:resolve` solved my problem.